# This SQLite query is returning a cursor with a count of 0... I know it should have at least 1. Can someone have a look? (Real quick)

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public Cursor fetchIsOverride(String username) {
        int override = 1;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, OVERRIDE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_ISOVERRIDE, KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_LASTNAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_WORKPHONE, KEY_PICTURE}, KEY_USERNAME + "= '" + username +"' " + "AND " + KEY_ISOVERRIDE + "=" + override, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

I have a row on the table with a KEY_ISOVERRIDE value of 1, and with the username I am querying. This is for certain. Can anyone see anything wrong with this syntax? I'm sure its in the WHERE clause, but as far as I can tell it's OK. Thanks.

Comment: If your DB is using case-sensitive mode.. make sure the case of username you are passing matched with the field value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being an idiot and including both `moveToFirst()`; AND a while loop like:

```
while(moveToNext()) {
    //stuff
}
```

Sorry for the trouble. But maybe someone else will catch their mistake this way too.

Answer (score 0):

If your `username` or `override` string has any punctuation, spaces, or other unusual characters, it may need to be escaped. It's better to use the parameter binding apis instead of interpolating strings directly into the SQL statements.

Comment: The username string is an email address, so something like `emailadress@email.com`... but that isn't the problem, I have an identical query save for the KEY_OVERRIDE = override WHERE clause and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use double == instead of single in the condition section of your query like this

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, OVERRIDE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_ISOVERRIDE, KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_LASTNAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_WORKPHONE, KEY_PICTURE}, KEY_USERNAME + "== '" + username +"' " + "AND " + KEY_ISOVERRIDE + "==" + override, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Cursor c=db.query("tbl_TEMP", new String[]{"sitename"+" as name",
                "Website" +" as website","category" +" as category" },
                //"sitename"+"=?", new String[]{"iPhoneAppDeveloper"}, null, null, null);
                "sitename"+"=?", new String[] {"your string to find perticular record frm DB"} , null, null, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) 
         {
                String name,website,categoty; 
                int nameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name"); 
                int websiteColumn = c.getColumnIndex("website");
                int categoryColumn = c.getColumnIndex("category");

```
            do
            {
                // Get the field values
                    name = c.getString(nameColumn);
                    TvXmlData.append("\n" +name );
                    website = c.getString(websiteColumn);
                    TvXmlData.append("\n " + website );
                    categoty = c.getString(categoryColumn);
                    TvXmlData.append("\n " + categoty );

            } while (c.moveToNext());

     }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```